# Gravatar Imager Url not Working - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gravatar

I'm using a gem called 'img_gravatar' to get avatars for my users profiles.
The syntax is as follows:

```
img_gravtar(@user.email)
```

Which outputs

```
<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/747fb50017944a3ca06b77fc2d51ba3b" />
```

The output is an img tag the works, but the tag is just displayed as text in the browser. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would bet you are in Rails3, and the output is escaped HTML.

try

```
img_gravtar(@user.email).html_safe
```